# Circle Container under content

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I need to place a block above the main content block. Tried use Positioned but does not give the desired result. Example:

[image]

My dart:

```
class _PaymentRouteState extends State<PaymentRoute> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFe8f0fa),
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Image.asset(
          'assets/logo.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          height: 45,
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/background.png"),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:40, bottom:40),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.35),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                            ),
                            child:Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                  Center(
                                      child:Text(
                                        'Способы оплаты',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0xFF4f4f4f),
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        ),
                                      )
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                          Container(
                                              padding:EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                              margin:EdgeInsets.only(top:10, right:10),
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                                  boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                                      BoxShadow(
                                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(61, 83, 116, 0.12),
                                                          blurRadius: 15.0,
                                                          offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75)
                                                      )
                                                  ],
                                              ),
                                              child:SvgPicture.asset(
                                                'assets/icons/mastercard-logo.svg',
                                                width:20,
                                                height:20
                                              ),
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            padding:EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                            margin:EdgeInsets.only(top:10, right:10),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                              boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                                BoxShadow(
                                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(61, 83, 116, 0.12),
                                                    blurRadius: 15.0,
                                                    offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75)
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            child:SvgPicture.asset(
                                                'assets/icons/visa-logo.svg',
                                                width:20,
                                                height:20
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Opacity(
                                              opacity: 0.4,
                                              child:Container(
                                                padding:EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                                margin:EdgeInsets.only(top:10, right:10),
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                                  boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                                    BoxShadow(
                                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(61, 83, 116, 0.12),
                                                        blurRadius: 15.0,
                                                        offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75)
                                                    )
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                                child:SvgPicture.asset(
                                                    'assets/icons/qiwi-logo.svg',
                                                    width:20,
                                                    height:20
                                                ),
                                              )
                                          ),
                                          Opacity(
                                              opacity: 0.4,
                                              child:Container(
                                                padding:EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                                margin:EdgeInsets.only(top:10, right:10),
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                                  boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                                    BoxShadow(
                                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(61, 83, 116, 0.12),
                                                        blurRadius: 15.0,
                                                        offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75)
                                                    )
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                                child:SvgPicture.asset(
                                                    'assets/icons/webmoney-logo.svg',
                                                    width:20,
                                                    height:20
                                                ),
                                              )
                                          ),
                                          Opacity(
                                              opacity: 0.4,
                                              child:Container(
                                                padding:EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                                margin:EdgeInsets.only(top:10, right:10),
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                                  boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                                    BoxShadow(
                                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(61, 83, 116, 0.12),
                                                        blurRadius: 15.0,
                                                        offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75)
                                                    )
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                                child:SvgPicture.asset(
                                                    'assets/icons/yandex-logo.svg',
                                                    width:20,
                                                    height:20
                                                ),
                                              )
                                          )
                                      ]
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 30),
                                  Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                                      boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                        BoxShadow(
                                            color: Color.fromRGBO(61, 83, 116, 0.12),
                                            blurRadius: 15.0,
                                            offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75)
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    child: TextField(
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                        hintText: 'E-mail для обратной связи',
                                        border: InputBorder.none,
                                        contentPadding:
                                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left:25, right:25, bottom:10),
                                    child:Text(
                                      'Сумма заказа',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color(0xFF4f4f4f),
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                                      child:Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Container(
                                                width:100,
                                                child:Text(
                                                  '30 AZN',
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Color(0xFF4f4f4f),
                                                    fontSize: 16,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                                child:FButton(
                                                  padding:EdgeInsets.only(top:10, bottom:10, left:15, right:15),
                                                  text: "Перейти к оплате",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.white
                                                  ),
                                                  color: Color(0xffFFc900),
                                                  image: Image.asset('assets/icons/btn-arrow.png', height:10),
                                                  imageAlignment: ImageAlignment.right,
                                                  gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                                                    Color(0xff6099d7),
                                                    Color(0xff789eeb),
                                                  ]),
                                                  onPressed: () {},
                                                  clickLoading: true,
                                                  loadingColor: Colors.white,
                                                  loadingText: "Loading...",
                                                  corner: FCorner.all(30),
                                                )
                                            )
                                          ]
                                      )
                                  )
                              ]
                            )
                        )
                      ]
                  )
              )
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Circle design:

```
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(20.0),
    ),
    child: Stack(
        children: < Widget > [
            Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: < Widget > [
                        Image.asset(
                            'assets/psplus-1month.png',
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            width: constraints.maxWidth,
                            height: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 28),
                        Text(
                            'Playstation Plus',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: const Color(0xFF4F4F4F),
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 5),
                        Text(
                            '1 месяц',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: const Color(0xFFA5ABC8),
                                    fontSize: 12,
                            ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 5),
                        Text(
                            '1 500 рублей',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: const Color(0xFF789EEB),
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
            Positioned(
                bottom: constraints.maxHeight / 2 - 20,
                left: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: < Widget > [
                        Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                        blurRadius: 7,
                                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.10),
                                        spreadRadius: 2)
                                ],
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                radius: 18,
                                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                    'assets/icons/wallet.svg',
                                    width: 25,
                                    height: 21
                                ),
                            ),
                        )
                    ],
                ),
            ),
        ],
    ),
)
```

The block must be completely rounded and placed above the main content block, aligning to the center. Does the flitter have something like z-index in css? I am having a problem with the block under the main block

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget to achieve that.
Example: I want to place The widget Widget_A on top of the Widget_B.

```dart
  Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Widget_B,
      Widget_A
    ],
  )
```

You can use the alignment parameter or the [`Positioned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) Widget to center your block:

```dart
  Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Widget_B,
      Widget_A
      Positioned(
        top: ...,
        right: ...,
        child: CenteredWidget,
      )
    ],
  )
```